# How to Ensure that Microsoft.Interop.Excel.Workbook.SaveAs Uses An SSIS Variable to Save Text File with Correct Filename?

Tags: c#, ssis, office-interop

I'm using the Microsoft.Interop.Excel library in my SSIS package's Script Task.  The Script Task is placed inside a For Each Loop Container that uses a file enumerator collection to iterate over all files with .xlsx suffix in a given folder.

The Script task runs without issue and produces the text file as anticipated.  However, the name of the text file should be obtained from a variable I pass into the Script Task e.g. MyTextFile.txt.  Instead, the Script Task creates the text file naming it MyExcelFile.xlsx_MyTextFile.txt.  The intended result is creation of a text file with the name MyTextFile.txt.

The contents of my Script task are as follows:

```
    Using Excel = Microsoft.Interop.Excel;
    public void Main()
    {
        try {
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            app.DisplayAlerts = false;
            Excel.Workbooks workbooks = app.Workbooks;
            Excel.Workbook workbook = workbooks.Open(Dts.Variables["User::Filename"].Value.ToString());
            Excel.Sheets worksheets = (Excel.Sheets)workbook.Sheets;
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];
            worksheet.Select(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
            string txtfilename = Dts.Variables["User::RXcurrentTextFilename"].Value.ToString();
            workbook.SaveAs(txtfilename, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlTextWindows);
            workbook.Close();
            workbooks.Close();
            app.Quit();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(worksheets);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(worksheet);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbooks);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook); 
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

The variable `RXcurrentTextFilename` is defined as an expression comprised of the UNC path, filename, current date and file extension as follows:

```
@[User::RXstagingFolder] + "_" + @[User::createDate]+@[User::RXtestFilename]
```

Note that the first variable contains the UNC path, the second variable returns the current date in yyyymmdd format and the third variable is the static value MyTextFile.txt.

How do I ensure that the Script Task creates the file with the naming convention exactly as defined in my variable?

Comment: Since this is SSIS, I'm guessing that you are going to be running it on a server.  Excel (and Excel interop) should never run on a server.  It may work when you test it, but it will fail - likely at the most inappropriate time: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2

Comment: Thanks for the perspective.  Looks like I need to pivot my approach.